# Encode Python list to UTF-8

Tags: python, list, encode

I have a python list that looks like that:

```
list = [u'a', u'b', u'c']
```

Now I want to encode it in UTF-8. Therefore I though I should use:

```
list = list[0].encode("utf-8")
```

But print list gives only

```
a
```

meaning the first element of the list. Not even a list anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want output as list or joined string?

Comment: you are reassigning the list variable to the first encoded letter

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
>>> items =  [u'a', u'b', u'c']
>>> [x.encode('utf-8') for x in items]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: @user2401772 Jamylak is very fast :)

Comment: doesn't work if you consider:
`>>> items =  [u'ç', u'á', u'í'] 
>>> ['\xc3\xa7', '\xc3\xa1', '\xc3\xad']`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I mean it if you consider `>>> items =  [u'ç', u'á', u'í']`  and if you do your suggestion `>>> [x.encode('utf-8') for x in items]` it will occur `>>> ['\xc3\xa7', '\xc3\xa1', '\xc3\xad']` i expected something like ['ç','á','í'].. Do you have any idea how to accomplished this?Or why doesn't work?

Comment: It is working, if you run `print '\xc3\xa7'` it will show you

Comment: ¡Great resource!

Answer (score 10):

`list[0]` is the first element, not a list. you are reassigning your `list` var to a new value, the utf-8 encoding of the first element.

Also, don't name your variables `list`, as it masks the `list()` function.

Comment: While the current accepted answer includes code examples that work, this answer responds to OP's question, "What am I doing wrong", and even takes it a step further to warn about `list` usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the output as a clean list without the unicodes:

```
import unicodedata

list1 = [u'a', u'b', u'c']
clean_list1 = [unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", x) for x in list1]
print(clean_list1)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need encode your string not decode. You are provided list consists of a unicode sting.  To represent unicode string as a string of bytes is known as encoding, use `u'...'.encode`. Then by using `string.split()` you can break encoded string down into smaller chunks ( strings )