# Convert string from unicode to utf-8 after stemming

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a simple string in utf-8 encoding. I am performing stemming using nltk stemmer. But after stemming, it converts the string to unicode. How can I convert it back to utf-8 encoding? Following is the code.

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

string = "something i am writing" 
string_before_Stem = string.split()
print string_before_Stem

['something', 'i', 'am', 'writing']

string = stemmer.stem(string)
string = string.split()
print string 

[u'something', u'i', u'am', u'writ']
```

Comment: Works for me, prints `['something', 'i', 'am', 'writ']`

Comment: @Henry, OP is using Python 2.  In Python 3 `'something'` *is* a Unicode string.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957226/encode-python-list-to-utf-8)

Comment: Why fight it?  Text *should* be Unicode, and in Python 3, Unicode strings are the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `encode` to do said task.

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

string = "something i am writing" 
string_before_Stem = string.split()
print string_before_Stem

['something', 'i', 'am', 'writing']

string = stemmer.stem(string)
string = string.split()

encoded_string = [s.encode('UTF-8', 'strict') for s in string]
```