# python3 TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
 for i in range(data.num_nodes):
        if embed[i]:
            # print embed[i]
            tmp = np.sum(embed[i], axis=0) / len(embed[i])
            file.write(' '.join(map(str.encode("utf-8"), tmp)) + '\n')
        else:
            file.write('\n')
```

However, when I run code, I get:

```
file.write(' '.join(map(str.encode("utf-8"), tmp)) + '\n')
`TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`
```

When I change the code into this:

```
  for i in range(data.num_nodes):
        if embed[i]:
            # print embed[i]
            tmp = np.sum(embed[i], axis=0) / len(embed[i])
            file.write(' '.join(map(str, tmp)) + '\n')
        else:
            file.write('\n')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: perhaps it has something to do with the fact that `str.encode("utf-8")` is not a function...? Please provide more explanations about what you're trying to do.

Comment: We can't figure out what exactly our problem is by the given piece of work. So provide your whole code, so that we can answer you

Comment: Ok, if I understood what you're trying to do (and what is the problem), I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957257/5462551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` expects a function object as its first argument, and with `str.encode("utf-8")` you actually call `str.encode` with `'utf-8'` as the first argument and literally encode the string `'utf-8'` to bytes, so when `map` calls the function in its first argument, it would fail as it is actually a string.

You should use `functools.partial` to pass `str.encode` to `map` `str.encode` as a function object with the `encoding` parameter pre-filled with your desired encoding:

```
from functools import partial
file.write(' '.join(map(partial(str.encode, encoding='utf-8'), tmp)) + '\n')
```

But since the `encoding` parameter for `str.encode` has a default value of `'utf-8'`, you can simply make `map` use the defaults of `str.encode` by passing `str.encode` to `map` directly:

```
file.write(' '.join(map(str.encode, tmp)) + '\n')
```

But since what you really want to do is to convert the entire string you're going to pass to `file.write` as bytes, including both `' '` and `'\n'`, which are strings rather than bytes, you should encode the entire string after the joining of the substrings and the concatenation with `'\n'`:

```
file.write((' '.join(tmp) + '\n').encode())
```

And since your `tmp` is not a list of strings, but rather a list of `numpy.float32` objects, you should map them to strings first before joining:

```
file.write((' '.join(map(str, tmp)) + '\n').encode())
```

Comment: I use :file.write(' '.join(list(map(str.encode, tmp))) + '\n') 
however,  TypeError happen: descriptor 'encode' requires a 'str' object but received a 'numpy.float32'

Comment: I see. Please see the last solution in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
file.write(' '.join(map(str.encode, tmp)) + '\n')
```

Instead of:

```
file.write(' '.join(map(str.encode("utf-8"), tmp)) + '\n')
```

Because `str.encode` needs a argument of a string and this works because default it's already `utf-8` encoding

Comment: Won't `str.encode` be a function? It's expecting a `bytes` object. So in theory, shouldn't you do `bytes(str, 'UTF-8')` to convert it as such? This is without knowing what `str` is.